# How to set seek bar value in Android?

Tags: android

Im developing one application which used SeekBar to control volume in 
MediaPlayer. The problem is when i move the seek bar at that time only the 
volume is increased, rest of 
the time default volume was set. Here is my code

```
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) 
    {
        //Log.i("Seek Bar", "" + validBpm);
        mp.setVolume(left, right);
    }
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
        left=left+20;
        right=right+20;
        mp.setVolume(left, right);
    }
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        left=left-20;
        right=right-20;
        mp.setVolume(left, right);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple fix although your original questions verbiage is really difficult to understand.

You're trying to use your own formula to set the volume and it doesn't look like those 2 methods are a good place to do it.  Those two methods should only fire once, since they are only a startTouch or finishTouch.

You need to be using the "progress" integer provided from the onProgressChanged method to set the volume to the mediaplayer accordingly.  This integer is the value of where the user set the seekBar.